# Restart Slow Mission Control in Yosemite

Tags: macos, mission-control

I'm getting some pretty high lag for Mission Control in Yosemite a couple hours after launch. I just want to restart the process but this no longer works:

```
killall Dock
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Mission Control is attached to the `WindowServer` process now. You can kill it using:

```
sudo kill -9 `pgrep WindowServer`
```

Note that this will log you out but is faster than a full system restart.

To mitigate future slowdowns, Reduce Transparency in your Accessibility settings before running the command:

[image: reduce transparency]

Comment: Reduce Transparency didn't work for me, but Increase Contrast did. Looks ugly now though.